# How to fix 'TypeError: undefined is not an object' during import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to organize my common `theme` folder in React Native. But found a problem when trying to default export a module in a different file. Basically, trying to do this basic structure:

```
+-- components
+-- theme
|  +-- appStyles.js
|  +-- colors.js
|  +-- index.js
```

In `theme/appStyles.js` would export default a single object (same for `colors.js`):

```
export default {
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
};
```

In `theme/index.js` looks like this where it'll export default an object, mapping the files in the theme folder:

```
import AppStyles from './appStyles';
import Colors from './colors';

export default {
  AppStyles,
  Colors,
};
```

When I'm trying to use this in another module, i.e. `SomeComponent.js`, it would just be undefined and would be unusable:

```
import { AppStyles } from '../theme';

console.log(AppStyles); // would log 'undefined'
```

---

As a work around, I've been doing:

In `theme/appStyles.js`:

```
export const AppStyles = {
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
};
```

In `theme/index.js`:

```
export * from './appStyles';
```

It would then be usable in `SomeComponent.js`:

```
import { AppStyles } from '../theme';

console.log(AppStyles); // would log Object structure
```

---

Been using this 'pattern' in ReactJS Web. Just wondering how does React Native handle this module resolution.

Answer (score 1):

No need to wrap default export by `{}`

```
import AppStyles from './appStyles';

export default AppStyles;
```

Than simply import with whatever name you want

```
import  AppStyles  from '../theme';

console.log(AppStyles);
```

I have multiple things to be exported from index

```
import  AppStyles  from '../theme';
import  Color from '../color';
export{
  Appstyle as default,
  Color
}
```

Than simply import as

```
import  AppStyles, {Color}  from '../theme';

console.log(AppStyles);
console.log(Color);
```

Comment: There are other files that could be in the theme folder like `colors.js`, `fonts.js`. And then would want to be exported from the `index.js` file as `{ Colors, Fonts, AppStyles }`.

Comment: @Ardemenial `../theme` will always point to `index.js`, if you want to club all the files exported values in single file, you can use `named export` in `index` and then `import with name`

Comment: Got it! Had a re-read from the docs. Thought it was react-native specific, since I was encountering some issues with the bundler before. Thanks!